# How to reverse Wordpress date feed in twig / timber?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

after many hours of trying every possible approach to this I turn to you. I have this website where is event calendar here

https://www.valtickepodzemi.cz/nase-sluzby/kalendar-akci-komplet/

But the problem is that on the top of the calendar is last month of the year (prosinec = December) and at the bottom is current date.

I need to reverse this feed. I need to start current date (the event that is closest to this current date) and at the bottom should be last event in this year.

Here is code of the calendar. I think it won't be difficult to change that but I can't figure out what part of code is responsible of making feed ASC or DESC.

Thank you very much any opinion

```
      <div style="display: -webkit-flex; display: -moz-flex; display: -ms-flex; display: -o-flex; display: flex;">
        <div class="events-calendar">
          <div class="calendar-head">
            {% if params.archive != true %}
              <h3>{{ __( 'Kalendář akcí', 'vp' ) }} {{ posts[0].event_start|date( 'm/d/Y' ) }}</h3>
            {% else %}
              <h3>{{ __( 'Archiv minulých akcí', 'vp' ) }} {{ posts[0].event_start|date( 'Y' ) }}</h3>
            {% endif %}

            {% if params.archive != true %}
              <a href="{{ post.link }}archiv" class="btn">{{ __( 'Archiv minulých akcí', 'vp' ) }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          
          {% for index,item in posts %}
            {% set current_date = item.event_start|date( 'F' ) %}

            {% if index == 0 %}
              <h4 >{{ item.event_start|date( 'F' ) }}</h4>

              <table class="events">
                <tbody>
            {% endif %}

            {% if index != 0 %}
              {% set f = index - 1 %}
              {% set old_month = posts[f].event_start|date( 'F' ) %}
              {% set old_year = posts[f].event_start|date( 'Y' ) %}

              {% if item.event_start|date( 'Y' ) != old_year %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <div class="calendar-head">
                  {% if params.archive != true %}
                    <h3>{{ __( 'Kalendář akcí', 'vp' ) }} {{ item.event_start|date( 'Y' ) }}</h3>
                  {% else %}
                    <h3>{{ __( 'Archiv minulých akcí', 'vp' ) }} {{ item.event_start|date( 'Y' ) }}</h3>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>

                <h4>{{ item.event_start|date( 'F' ) }}</h4>

                <table class="events">
                <tbody>
              {% elseif item.event_start|date( 'F' ) != old_month %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
                
                <h4>{{ item.event_start|date( 'F' ) }}</h4>

                <table class="events">
                <tbody>
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {#<tr id="{{ item.slug }}-{{ item.event_start|date( 'Y' ) }}" class="event" data-start-day="{{ item.event_start|date('d') }}" data-start-month="{{ item.event_start|date('m') }}" data-start-year="{{ item.event_start|date('Y') }}">
              <td class="thumbnail">
                {{ function( 'get_the_post_thumbnail', item.id, 'event-calendar-thumb' ) }}
              </td>

              <td class="dates">
                <!-- 23. - 24.3. -->
                {% if item.get_field( 'event_start' ) and item.get_field( 'event_end' ) %}
                  {{ item.get_field( 'event_start' ) }} - {{ item.get_field( 'event_end' ) }}
                {% elseif item.get_field( 'event_start' ) %}
                  {{ item.get_field( 'event_start' ) }}
                {% endif %}
                <!-- <span class="gray">
                  2018
                </span> -->
              </td>

              <td class="content">
                <h2>
                  {{ item.title }}
                </h2>

                <h3>
                  {{ item.subtitle }}
                </h3>

                <div class="hidden">
                  {{ item.content }}

                  <a href="{{ item.link }}rezervace" class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ __( 'Rezervovat', 'vp' ) }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td class="toggle">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-toggle">
                  {{ __( 'Info', 'vp' ) }}
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>#}

            <tr id="{{ item.slug }}-{{ item.event_start|date( 'Y' ) }} " class="event {% if item.event_start and item.event_end %}{% for date in range( item.event_start|date('U'), item.event_end|date('U'), 86400) %} {{ date|date('Y-m-d') }} {% endfor %}{% else %} {{ item.event_start|date('Y-m-d') }} {% endif %}" data-dates="">
              <td class="thumbnail">
                {{ function( 'get_the_post_thumbnail', item.id, 'event-calendar-thumb' ) }}
              </td>

              <td class="dates">
                <!-- 23. - 24.3. -->
                {% if item.get_field( 'event_start' ) and item.get_field( 'event_end' ) %}
                  {{ item.get_field( 'event_start' ) }} - {{ item.get_field( 'event_end' ) }}
                {% elseif item.get_field( 'event_start' ) %}
                  {{ item.get_field( 'event_start' ) }}
                {% endif %}
                <!-- <span class="gray">
                  2018
                </span> -->
              </td>

              <td class="content">
                <h2>
                  {{ item.title }}
                </h2>

                <h3>
                  {{ item.subtitle }}
                </h3>

                <div class="hidden">
                  {{ item.content }}

                  <a href="{{ item.link }}rezervace" class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ __( 'Rezervovat', 'vp' ) }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td class="toggle">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-toggle">
                  {{ __( 'Info', 'vp' ) }}
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            {% if index == ( function( 'count', posts ) - 1 ) %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Comment: We can't do anything from what you gave us, please consider editing with full page source code

Comment: Could you show us the what you do in PHP, before you render that Twig view?